# Updating in vtiger from Javascript. Permission to perform the operation is denied for id

Tags: javascript, vtiger, vtigercrm

I have a node application that needs to be integrated into vtiger, and I have successfully been able to create, delete and retrieve information from my vtiger instance. If I try to update however, I get a **Permission to perform the operation is denied for id** error.

I have tried a couple different methods i.e. different ways of performing the request. And to test it at the moment I am pulling all of the data (`result` in the below code) for an id, changing one value and then calling the update using:

```
var requestJS = require('request');

//Real result comes stright from CRM, but an example of what is being passed through
result = {
    'lastname': 'Updated last name',
    'id': '12x10',
    'assigned_user_id': '19x5',
}

var url = VT_URL + '?operation=update&sessionName=' + session + '&element=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(result));
requestJS.post(url, function(err, res, body){
    //stuff here
});
```

I have also tried by attaching the result as the body, and by not using the encodeUriComponent function. Always the same error.

where `VT_URL` is my vitger url and `session` is my session id retrieved from login.

I am using the credentials of an admin so I should have read/write access to contacts in the CRM instance.

I have been stuck on this for a while and can't find an answer

Answer (score 0):

So it's not really an answer, but as I changed to a new vtiger instance it all seemed to work fine. So I'm assuming it was more to do with the installation of vtiger rather than an error in the code.

Thought I would keep this question here though because I've seen it around a fair bit

Answer (score 0):

Can you check on your previous vtiger instance if there is an entry (in the database) for your module (I assume Contacts) in the **vtiger_ws_entity** table ?

If yes, ID is 12 ?

Comment: Mine was under __vtiger_ws_entity__, but yes, Contacts does have the id 12